# Remote Join/ReJoin a PC to Domain

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use my domain pc to join/rejoin other pcs that have fallen off the domain. I have two test computers I am working with and it doesn't work with either. One is join and working on the domain and the other has fallen off the domain. Both are networked hardline to the domain for this process. I keep running into this issue when running my script. How can I resolve my error?

```
Remove-Computer : Cannot establish the WMI connection to the computer 'JoinTest' with the following error message: 
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
```

```
$CorpDomain = "Domain.com\"
$ComputerName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Target Computer Name?'
$AdminCreds = Read-Host -Prompt 'Admin account username'
$DomainAdmin = $CorpDomain+$AdminCreds
$LocalCreds = $ComputerName+"\Administrator"

Remove-Computer -ComputerName $ComputerName -UnjoinDomaincredential 
$DomainAdmin  -PassThru -Verbose -Restart


Add-Computer -ComputerName $ComputerName -LocalCredential $LocalCreds - 
DomainName "Domain.com" -Credential $DomainAdmin -Force -Verbose -Restart

#Allow time for reboot
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

Get-ADComputer $ComputerName -Properties *
```

Comment: First question, can you ping the device in question? Second, when you are declaring the CORP domain variable dont include the .com at the end of it. Just use "domain\"

Comment: For the first question: Yes I can ping the device though I could put in a ling to ping the device before moving forward.
Second: the domain has .com in it. not sure why the have it that way here.

Comment: Try the script again and remove the .com from your domain variable. This is how it always works, if the admin account is located in the Forest you would do "Domain\Administrator" if you had a child domain like `corp.domain.com` you would use "CORP\administrator". Try with just Domain and see what that gets you.

Comment: I get the exact same error. At this point, lets assume my account doesn't have full admin privileges on the network. This will cause this error correct?

For the local account, I'm trying to use the local admin account because all of our machines are imaged with it on there.

Comment: Yes it seems like you do not have wmi access on the machine in question. If you add yourself to the local admin group this should not be a problem.

Comment: I'm not sure thing is going to work. Once the computer is no longer trusted by the domain you won't be able to authenticate to it unless your credentials are cached. It's possible to use non-domain credentials but since Kerberos isn't an option you'll have to use HTTPS based transport or make an exception (on both ends) to allow HTTP based transport.

Comment: Right. So instead of using a remove/rejoin method. I am going to try do a trust rebuild with the machine. Loosly based:

Reset-ComputerMachinePassword -Server DomainController -Credential Domain\Username

Answer (score 0):

If the PC's are not already in the domain but all have PS remoting enabled and share the same local Administrator username/password, you can use:

```
$localUser = "Administrator"
$localPassword = "YourPasswordHere"
$localCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Argumentlist $localUser, $localPassword

$domainUser = "Domain\Username"
$domainPasswrod = "YourPasswordHere"
$domainCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Argumentlist $domainUser, $domainPassword

[array]$computers = @("pc01", "pc02")

$scriptBlock = {
    Add-Computer -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -LocalCredential $args[0] -DomainName "Domain.com" -Credential $args[1] -Force -Restart
}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList $localCreds, $domainCreds
```

You can use [PowerShell remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-6) with commands like `Invoke-Command` where you specify the remote computer to execute the command you want (i.e. `Add-Computer`). Obviously you need PS remoting enabled (catch 22) before you can use this method.

Comment: So it seems like the network here has the ports blocked or not configured for WinRM.

“WinRM service will use for either HTTP or HTTPS. WinRM 2.0: The default HTTP port is 5985, and the default HTTPSport is 5986. Specifies the IPv4 or IPv6 addresses that listeners can use.”

So I am working on clearing that up...I do like your writing better for the coding. I'll try it out. I do want to force the admin to type their creds each time and not store it in the script itself so I could make the modifications for that. Appreciate the insight! Still newer to PS.